# Easy way to send emails using SMTP from Amazon Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email

I have a business website hosted at Amazon's server. We are currently using Amazon's SNS to send email but we would like to setup our own email system based on SMTP. If you have any ideas about how to do , I would like to request for you suggestions /ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on AWS already, easiest thing to do is use their SES product - a drop-in replacement for an SMTP server - you really don't want to run your own on an EC2 instance - your deliverability rates will likely go way down if you try as the EC2 instances and ip addresses ranges are often abused by spammers.

Comment: I read that we have to pay for using SES. Or is it free. Previous developer had implemented SNS(simple notification service) but they want to replace it because they don't want to pay for SNS.